# Child output appears before the main process call it using system()

Tags: c++, linux

I have the following situation

```
std::cout<<"--------------------------\n";
std::cout<<argument<<"\n";
std::cout<<"--------------------------\n";
const char *command;
command=argument.c_str();
int status = system(command);
if(status==-1) 
{
 error_number=-2;
 clean_up();
 return error_number;
 }
 /*
    calculation();// few ms...
 */
 // 
 const char *command;
 command=argument2.c_str();
 int status = system(command);
 //
```

the shell script of the second command echo few strings.
Now the output instead of the expected A is the B.(?!)

A)
     --------------------------

```
my_command1.sh var1 var2 var3 //  2 minute wall clock, 20 msec cpu time
 --------------------------
 ********************************************
 *** welcome to e_calcsym_ver3.sh                       
 *** Debug  mode                                      
 ********************************************
```

B)
      --------------------------

```
 my_command1.sh var1 var2  ********************************************
*** welcome to e_calcsym_ver3.sh                        
*** Debug mode                                                      
********************************************var3
--------------------------
```

The second situation occurred when I had 12+ process to run in parallel.
During the debugging, running only one process, always I have the first situation.
Any idea?

Comment: Why is this tagged c?

Comment: What does this have to do with parallel programming? Or the Linux Kernel? And what are argument and argument2?

Comment: 10+ process parallel, and the mixed of the output happens inside the kernel

Answer (score 0):

The outputs of the two processes are mixed, because in the parent proceess you only write to a buffer that is lateron flushed. Either use `cout << flush` or use `cout << endl` instead of `cout << '\n'`, because `endl` will output a newline and flush the buffers.